# How to make a client connect to multiple host with the same client bootstrap in netty 4?

Tags: java, network-programming, netty

In this code When the client connects to a new Server the previously connected channel with the server gets inactive and that channel gets allocated to the newly connected server. I want a way to store all the channels this can be done by allocating a  separate channel for each connected server.

```
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
try {
    Bootstrap client = new Bootstrap();
    client.group(workerGroup);
    client.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
    client.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
    @Override
     public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new ObjectEncoder(),new ObjectDecoder(ClassResolvers.weakCachingResolver(Message.class.getClassLoader())),new ClientHandler());
            }
     });
     Thread.sleep(10000);

     ChannelFuture future = client.connect("localhost", destination_Port).sync();
     if(future.isSuccess()) {
         System.out.println("Connected to node " +destination_Node + " port is "+ destination_Port);
         // Storing the channel in the map to reuse later
         channelMap.put(destination_Node,future);
     }
     // data is an object which will be sent to the server 
     data.setSender(nodeID);
     data.setClockTime(clockTime);
     future.channel().writeAndFlush(data);
}
finally {
     workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
}
```

From the sources i went through i understand that with the help of a ChannelFactory i will be able to have a separate channel for each connected host but i was not able to implement it can someone help me with this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you asking for... Just call connect multiple times. Each will return a new Channel which represent a new connection.